# Content not crawled by SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, sharepoint-search

I am facing an issue where content is not crawled properly by SharePoint 2013. Following warning is displayed in crawled logs.

> The claims cookie used by the crawler has expired. ( Error from
>   SharePoint site: HttpStatusCode Unauthorized The request failed with
>   HTTP status 401: Unauthorized., CorrelationID: "guid"; SearchID = GUID
>   )

Any one having this issue or know solution to it?
Thanks.

EDIT: We have added custom HTTP module for sliding session and we expire cookie after 30 minutes.

Comment: What authentication isbeing used in default zone of the web application

Comment: Can the crawl account open the site from the browser on the crawl server without error?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE It is activated both windows and trusted identity on default zone.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott yes the crawl account can open the site with out errors.

Comment: Are you testing from the crawl server and is the crawl account getting the cookie? Have you tried an alternate authentication and specifying the cookie? Since you are using custom auth have you considered moving auth to a different zone and have the default zone use windows claims?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott The problem was that i was expiring cookie for all accounts.  I changed the sliding session a bit and now i am expiring cookie only for accounts from identity provider. This solved the issue.